# How Convergence in two different norms relates to Equivalence of Norms

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Question:**  Why was this marked as a duplicate?  The referenced question asked nearly a year later than this question.  In fact I'm not even sure that they are identical at all.

---

I was working on a homework problem which stated:

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space with two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$.  Assume that $\|x_n - x^1\|_1\to 0$ for some $x^1\in X$ if and only if $\|x_n - x^2\|_2\to 0$ for some $x^2\in X$.  Show that $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent.

At first I errantly misinterpreted the question as $x_n\to x$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$ if and only if $x_n\to x$ in $\|\cdot\|_2$.

UPDATE:  I found a way to go directly from the convergence condition to equivalence of norms.  So I don't need to prove that the sequences converge to the same limit in this way (since it now follows from equivalence of norms).  I won't erase anything though, as the answer from Andres below may be helpful to someone else.

Now that I realize my mistake I'm trying to fix the proof.  Since the conclusion I'm trying to prove (that the norms are equivalent) implies that the limits in either norm must agree, I know that must also be true, even though it's not given in the question.  After failing to prove this extra condition, I am getting suspicious that it might be needed as a hypothesis after all.  Can anyone confirm or refute this?

My attempt:

Taking $\alpha = \dfrac12\min\left(\|x^1 - x^2\|_1, \|x^1 - x^2\|_2\right)$,

I let $B_{1} = \{x\in X : ||x - x^1||_{1} < \alpha\}$ and
let $B_{2} = \{x\in X : ||x - x^{2}||_{2} < \alpha\}$.

Now suppose for a contradiction that there is some $x\in B_{1}\cap B_{2}$.  Then $||x - x^{1}||_{1} < \alpha$.  And $||x - x^{2}||_{2} < \alpha$.  I want to use this to prove $||x^{1} - x^{2}||$ (in either norm) is less than $2\alpha$ (which would give me a contradiction).  But I keep ending up with these floating $||x - x^{2}||_{1}$ or $||x - x^{1}||_{2}$ terms that I can't do anything with:

$
\begin{eqnarray*}
||x^{1} - x^{2}||_{1} &\leq& ||x^{1} - x||_{1} + ||x - x^{2}||_{1}\\
&<& \alpha + ||x - x^{2}||_{1}
\end{eqnarray*}
$

and

$
\begin{eqnarray*}
||x^{1} - x^{2}||_{2} &\leq& ||x^{1} - x||_{2} + ||x - x^{2}||_{2}\\
&<& ||x^{1} - x||_{2} + \alpha
\end{eqnarray*}
$

Comment: Are you missing something like "$ \to 0$" after the norms of those differences in the homework problem?

Comment: Shouldn’t those be $\|x_n-x^2\|_2\to 0$ and $\|x_n-x^1\|_1\to 0$?

Comment: Absolutely.  Thank you.

Comment: Is it valid for EVERY sequence $x_n$? Then take the constant sequence $x_n = x^1$.

Comment: Kyle: It would be great if you posted your solution as an answer if you have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_n = x^1$.
Then, since $x_n \rightarrow x^1$ in any norm, we have that $\|x^1 - x^2\|_2 = \|x_n - x^2\|_2 \rightarrow 0$. That is, $x^1 = x^2$.

The above means that the identity
$i: (X, \|\cdot\|_1) \rightarrow (X, \|\cdot\|_2)$
is continuous with continuous inverse at $x^1$.
But this means that the identity is a homeomorphism.
Now, this is "my definition" of equivalent norms:
when the topology induced by both is the same.
And this is the same as saying that the identity is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Our definition is that each norm is uniformly bounded by a constant multiple of the other.  Of course both definitions are equivalent, but our homework problem was essentially to justify that.

This definitely works.  So thanks for this.  I already submitted my argument which actually went directly from the convergence condition to the definition (my definition) of equivalence of norms.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** As Kyle pointed out, the answer below is not correct.

---

Take $\alpha = \dfrac12\min\left(\|x^1 - x^2\|_1, \|x^1 - x^2\|_2\right)$.
Now, notice that the ball of radius $\alpha$ around $x^1$ in the first norm does not intersect the ball of radius $\alpha$ around $x^2$ in the second norm.

This means that the sequence cannot be in both balls at the same time.

Comment: Very elegant.  Thank you times a million - I can modify my argument with this trick now.

Comment: @ André Caldas: For some reason I am still stuck - although I geometrically see (if one can visualize two norms simultaneously...) why this should work. (See edits above.)

Comment: @Kyle: It was very elegant... but completely wrong, it seems... :-)  
Sorry if I mislead you!

Comment: No problem whatsoever!  I got where I needed to go in the end. :)

Thanks for helping all the same.